# If $s,y\in\mathbb R^n$ with $s\ne 0$ and $s^Ty>0$, then $Q:=I+\frac{y-v}{v^Tv}v^T$ with $v:=\sqrt{\frac{s^Ty}{s^Ts}}s$ is regular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $s,y\in\mathbb R^n$ with $s\ne 0$ and $\langle s,y\rangle>0$. Moreover, let $$v:=\sqrt{\frac{\langle s,y\rangle}{\langle s,s\rangle}}s\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;Q:=I+\frac{y-v}{\langle v,v\rangle}v^T\;.$$ How can we show, that $Q$ is regular?

---

I tried to show, that the only solution of $Qx=0$ is $x=0$. Obviously, $Qx=0$ is equivalent to $$x=-\frac{y-v}{\langle v,v\rangle}v^Tx\;,$$ which implies that $$\frac{y-v}{\langle v,v\rangle}v^T=-I\;,\tag{1}$$ if $x\ne 0$. Can we derive a contradiction from $(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work. That $x=Ax$ for some $A$ doesn't mean $A=I$.

To prove the problem statement, let $v_1=v$ and extend it to an orthogonal basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$.

1. Show that $Qv_i\ne0$ for every $i$.
2. Explain why $Q$ is invertible when the previous statement is true. (*Hint:* if $Q$ is singular, $x^TQ=0$ for some $x\ne0$.)

Comment: Clearly, $Qv_1=y\ne 0$ (since $s\ne 0$ and $\langle s,y\rangle>0$). Can we use $Qv_{i-1}\ne 0$ to show $Qv_i\ne 0$?

Comment: I've tried to use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality: $$\left\|Qv_i\right\|\ge\frac 1{\left\|v_{i-1}\right\|}\langle Qv_i,v_{i-1}\rangle=\frac 1{\left\|v_{i-1}\right\|}\langle v_i,Qv_{i-1}\rangle\;,$$ but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Let $$b=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jv_j$$ be the representation of $b:=Qv_{i-1}\ne 0$ with respect to $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. Since $\left\|v_{i-1}\right\|=1$, we've got $$\left\|Qv_i\right\|\ge \langle v_i,b\rangle=\lambda_i\;,$$ but $\lambda_i$ might be $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see: $$Qv_i=v_i+\frac{y-v_1}{\langle v_1,v_1\rangle }\underbrace{\langle v_1,v_i\rangle}_{=0}=v_i,.$$ but there is one problem: $v=v_1$ is of length $\sqrt{\langle s,y\rangle}\ne 1$. So, we should use $v_1:=v/\left\|v\right\|$.

Comment: Yes, $Qv_1=y/\left\|v\right\|$.

Comment: What you write know, is what I wrote in the first comment (and you mentioned, that I "probably calculated $Qv_1$ wrong". And you were right. If we define $v_1:=v/\left\|v\right\|$, then $$Qv_1=v_1+\frac{y-v}{\langle v,v\rangle}\langle v,v^1\rangle=v_1+\frac{y-v}{\left\| v\right\|}=\frac y{\left\| v\right\|}$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned. We cannot take $v_1=v$ since $\left\|v\right\|=\sqrt{\langle s,y\rangle}\ne 1$, which means, that we cannot *extend* $v^1$ to an ortho**normal**basis.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't read carefully enough.